# How do I initialize a two-dimensional array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to initialize two copies of the same two-dimensional arrays in C.  However, only one stores the correct data:

```
    //convert 1D array to 2D array
double** myA = malloc(n*sizeof(double*));
for (j=0;j<n;j++)
    myA[j]=&a[j*n];

double** myS = (double **) malloc(n*sizeof(double*));
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    for (j=0; j<n; j++){
        myS[i] = (double *) malloc(n*sizeof(double));
        myS[i][j] = myA[i][j];
    }

printf("A:\n");
print_matrix(myA,n);
printf("S:\n");
print_matrix(myS,n);
```

I want to initialize two copies of A.  One as myA and the other as myS.  However, here is my output:

```
A:
0.000000 1.000000 2.000000 3.000000 4.000000 
1.000000 1.414214 2.236068 3.162278 4.123106 
2.000000 2.236068 2.828427 3.605551 4.472136 
3.000000 3.162278 3.605551 4.242641 5.000000 
4.000000 4.123106 4.472136 5.000000 5.656854 

S:
-0.000000 -0.000000 -0.000000 -0.000000 4.000000 
-0.000000 -0.000000 -0.000000 -0.000000 4.123106 
-0.000000 -0.000000 -0.000000 -0.000000 4.472136 
-0.000000 -0.000000 -0.000000 -0.000000 5.000000 
-0.000000 -0.000000 -0.000000 -0.000000 5.656854
```

Why are all the columns but the last `-0.000000`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overwriting each row buffer N-1 times (and leaking memory like a sieve leaks water in the process).

Change this:

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    for (j=0; j<n; j++){
        myS[i] = (double *) malloc(n*sizeof(double));
        myS[i][j] = myA[i][j];
    }
```

To this:

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    myS[i] = malloc(n*sizeof(double));
    for (j=0; j<n; j++)
        myS[i][j] = a[i*n+j];
}
```

Note two things in the above code:

1. [Don't cast malloc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)
2. The `myA` temp array is not needed. You can do the math with the index yourself. Throw that entire thing out.

Comment: I am manipulating myA seperately than myS; I need them both for different purposes.